# Rsync performance on on two Linux Machines

Tags: rsync, amazon-ec2, suse

I am having two Virtual Machines (**VM-source and VM-destination**) and each with an NFS filesystem. I want to sync data (1TB) between the two machines and I am worried about the CPU/Memory needed for each machine.

knowing that only one machine will run the sync command (**VM-source**), I assume this one will need to have a high CPU and RAM. is the same requirements needed for the other machine(**VM-destination**), which will just received Data ? what needs to be taking into consideration ?

For the record, one VM (**VM-source**) is hosted on Premise and the Other one is on AWS. Mounting Filesystem on the same machine was not possible

The number of files I try to sync is in 100,000s (very small files (less than a MB)), and the some of those files is almost 1.5TB.

Comment: How much would be too much CPU or RAM for you? RAM usage can go up with many files or really huge files, while CPU shouldn't be an issue as transfers tend to be IO bound (disk or network). Try giving information from the files you have and the machine specifications.
Partial syncs are an option to you? To avoid a too big sync at once?

Comment: very small files, some few KB and the total size is 1.5TB. there are hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: That's not a frighteningly large dataset. Are you going to use `rsync -H`? If not, there'll be very little problem just doing it.